# #import <JWPlayer-SDK/JWPlayerController.h> In Brigding header causing error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, media-player, jwplayer

Hi when i do #import  on my Bridging Header it cause error "Ambiguous use of 'tag' on my other controllers.
Im using tag in buttons.

Those anyone know this error?

Comment: Try just #import "JWPlayerController.h"

Comment: Hi Jecky im still getting the same error

Comment: U install this sdk using pod file ?

Comment: Yes im using pod file.

Comment: Just clean your project and run it again

Answer (score 0):

Just do following

Whenever you need to access this library on top of your class declaration write following line.

```
import JWPlayerController
```

I hope that helps.

Thank you!